# How do I pass grants with boto3's upload_file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto3

I have a command using the AWS CLI

```
aws s3 cp y:/mydatafolder s3://<bucket>/folder/subfolder --recursive --grants read=uri=http://policyurl
```

The first part is easy to do in python, I can use `os.walk` to walk the folders and get the files and upload the file using the `boto3.s3client.upload_file` command.  The second part I'm struggling with is the `--grants read` part.

What boto3 function do I need to call to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `upload_file` call you will need to pass `GrantRead` in `ExtraArgs`. Generally speaking you can pass in any arguments that [`put_object`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) would take this way. For example:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
file_path = '/foo/bar/baz.txt'
s3.upload_file(
    Filename=file_path,
    Bucket='<bucket>',
    Key='key',
    ExtraArgs={
        'GrantRead': 'uri="http://policyurl"'
    }
)
```